# How to pass string value from a view via Jquery.ajax() to ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a function in my view, like this :

```
function doIncriment() {
            var v1 = @ViewBag.CountNumber + 1;
            var v2 = @int.Parse(Request.QueryString["idForAnswer"]);
            var v3 = @int.Parse(Request.QueryString["View"]);
            var v5 = @int.Parse(Request.QueryString["answerNumber"]);
            var v6 = @Request.QueryString["title"];
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("pp", "Questions")',
                method: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: { votingUp : v1, questionId : v2 , viewNumber : v3, numberOfAnswer : v5 , titleString : v6 }
            }).done(function (d) {
                jQuery("#lblResult").text(d);
            });
        }
```

And my controller code like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public string pp(string votingUp, int questionId, int viewNumber, int numberOfAnswer, string titleString, [Bind(Include = "ID,Vote,Answer1,View,Title,Question,Date")] Questions questions)
            {
                questions.ID = questionId;
                questions.Vote = int.Parse(votingUp);
                questions.View = viewNumber;
                questions.Date = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-10 23:39:33.000");
                questions.Answer1 = numberOfAnswer;
                questions.Title = titleString.ToString();
                questions.Question = "test test";
                db.Entry(questions).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return (votingUp.ToString());
            }
```

The int values work fine. But whenever I try to pass any string or datetime data, the ajax call is not responding. How can I pass these values from my ajax function to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a string value, make sure your method parameter is also `string` type.  Currently you have `int` for the `titleString` parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public string pp(string votingUp, int questionId, int viewNumber, int numberOfAnswer, 
   string titleString, [Bind(Include = "ID,Vote,Answer1,View,Title,
                                                      Question,Date")] Questions questions)
{
   // to do : Return something
}
```

I also suggest you to make sure you are using the correct data types. If you are sending a numeric value (Ex : `votingUp` ) There is no need to use string first and convert it back. You can directly use the int type as parameter type and avoid the casting later

```
[HttpPost]
public string pp(int votingUp, int questionId, int viewNumber, int numberOfAnswer, 
   string titleString,
       [Bind(Include = "ID,Vote,Answer1,View,Title,Question,Date")] Questions questions)
{
  // to do : Return something
}
```

**EDIT** : As mmushtaq mentioned in the comment, you should wrap the value of `@Request.QueryString["title"]` in quotes so that it will be stored as string value in the variable `v6`

```
var v6 = '@Request.QueryString["title"]';
```

Comment: voting up is linked with vote. I think, this is not a problem.

Comment: Yea. See the updated answer. your `titleString` param type is wrong!

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It's still not working. Code updated.

Comment: Enclose title in quotes like this `var v6 = '@Request.QueryString["title"]';`

Comment: Thanks @mmushtaq. I missed that.

Comment: Thank you so much @mmushtaq